# Spirit Qi Parsing multilines from Console

Tags: c++, parsing, console, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am using the Console as an input source.
I looked for a way qi would parse a line and then it'd wait for the next line and continue parsing from that point.
for example take the following grammar

```
start = MultiLine | Line;
Multiline = "{" *(Line) "}";
Line = *(char_("A-Za-z0-9"));
```

As an input

```
{ AAAA
Bbbb
lllll
lalala
}
```

Taking the whole thing from a file is easy. 
But what should i do if i need to have the input to come from the console instead?
That i want to have it process what its given already and wait for the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "highlevel" idiomatic way to do this in Qi is `qi::match`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7af8b19dd3638fc3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>

using Line      = std::string;
using MultiLine = std::vector<Line>;

int main() {

    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    MultiLine block;
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    while (std::cin >> phrase_match('{' >> lexeme[*~char_("\r\n}")] % eol >> '}', blank, block))
    {
        std::cout << "Processing a block of " << block.size() << " lines\n";
        block.clear();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Processing a block of 4 lines
Processing a block of 7 lines
```

Where the second line appears after one second delay (due to the `sleep 1` used)

As Chris Beck was hinting, this uses `boost::spirit::istream_iterator` under the hood. You can also use that explicitly, e.g. if you want to use recursively nested rules.

Comment: Your answer is pretty informative, and it pretty much solved all my problems.
i will probably delve deeper into the istream_iterator that Chris mentioned later on. 
I actually was hoping for you to answer my question because of how informed into the subject you are from what i read of all answers to boost::spirit related questions. 
thank you for giving your time answering all our questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an istream iterator which you construct from `std::cin` for this. If your grammar is templated against `typename iterator` like Hartmut does in all the examples, then it should work fine.

It would be easy to illustrate if you provide an SSCCE. The istream iterator is only a few lines of code to create.

Comment: Thank you for the information, i'm looking further into it now.